# How can I push from my local repository to my server via terminal?

Tags: git, push, branch, hostname, nodename

I have a local git repository on my mac. I push my commits always to my git repository on github.

Now I finished my work and I want to push everything to my clients server (linux).

I follow this tutorial https://www.codesolutions.de/git-repository-lokal-erstellen-und-dann-auf-den-server-uploaden/

1. I uploaded everything to my server like this:

   `scp -r projectname.git user@meinserver.de:/home/meine-git-repositories/`
2. I created a new branch like this:

   `git remote add mynewbranch ssh://user@meinserver.de:home/meine-git-repositories/projectname.git`

Everything worked fine until now.

When I try:

```
git push mynewbranch master
```

I get the error message:

```
Could not resolve hostname meinserver:html: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I checked the `.ssh/config` and everything looks fine. I am also able to connect via ssh to the server. I do not know why it does not work now

Comment: `git remote add` does not create a *branch*. It creates a *remote*, i.e., a name for another Git repository. The other Git repository must exist by the time you use the name for it. Your `scp -r` is likely to have created a valid repository, but `scp`-ing the `.git` directory around is not a recommended method as it may leave inappropriate configuration settings in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked the .ssh/config and everything looks fin

Your URL should have worked *without* `~/.ssh/config` fie, so double-check it again.

```
Could not resolve hostname meinserver:html
```

It looks like the `git remote -v` or the `.ssh/config` reference a `meinserver:html` server hostname, instead of `meinserver.de`: that would be your issue.

---

The [OP peace-love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5024157/peace-love) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334015/how-can-i-push-from-my-local-repository-to-my-server-via-terminal/73340733#comment129934161_73340733):

> true! I wrote
>
> ```
> git remote add mynewbranch ssh://user@meinserver.de:home/meine-git-repositories/projectname.git
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> git remote add mynewbranch ssh://user@meinserver.de:/home/meine-git-repositories/projectname.git
> ```

Comment: true! I wrote `git remote add mynewbranch ssh://user@meinserver.de:home/meine-git-repositories/projectname.git`instead of `git remote add mynewbranch ssh://user@meinserver.de:/home/meine-git-repositories/projectname.git`

Comment: @peace_love Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer.